# Having a issue closing topLevel widget from another "def"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have two def's as seen below. One of them creates a topLevel widget with two button options. One of the buttons calls the other def. In the other def I want to close the topLevel widget using topLevelName.destroy(). But I keep getting an error saying topLevelName is not defined.

My code:

```
def func1():
    print("We are in func1.")
    topLevelName.destroy()      <---Error occurs here. 

def func2():
    topLevelName = tkinter.Toplevel()
    yesButton= tkinter.Button(topLevelName , text="Yes", command=func1)
    noButton= tkinter.Button(topLevelName , text="No",command=topLevelName.destroy)
```

Error Message:

```
NameError: name 'topLevelName' is not defined
```

Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly here?

Comment: Please use real terminology. You don't have two "defs", you have two functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `topLevelName` is local variable which means it can only be accessed inside of `func2`. If you want to access it outside of that scope, you should either make it global variable or use classes. For building relatively large GUIs using classes is much more better solution but for this one you can use globals.

```
topLevelName = None #create the variable in global scope

def func1():
    print("We are in func1.")
    topLevelName.destroy()

def func2():
    global topLevelName   #which means, the changes will be applied in global scope
    topLevelName = tkinter.Toplevel()
    yesButton= tkinter.Button(topLevelName , text="Yes", command=func1)
    noButton= tkinter.Button(topLevelName , text="No",command=topLevelName.destroy)
```